# How can I make this inner corner Bevel (modifier) look better without applying my Boole (modifier)?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I need to be able to keep this dynamic because the object I'm using for the boole is animated (the cavity grows in time).

After my Boole modifier I'm using a Bevel modifier.  The outer corner (green) of this bevel looks good, but I can't get the inner corner (red) to look right.  It's creating a hard edge triangle, but I want a totally round/smooth transition.

How can I pull this off while keeping it dynamic?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m63mts9s51apy2m/Bevel%20Modifier%20Corners%20How.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: On the bevel modifier, try changing the Geometry section's Miter Inner to Patch or Sharp; seems like an improvement.  Also, Profile::Shape looks better at 0,57 instead of 0.50.  But of course you'd want to check the rendering against more simulated frames.

Comment: Thanks @james_t. There is no 'patch' option for Miter Inner, and Arc would look good but it also creates a hard edged triangle